# Angular select with initial value

Tags: html, angular, forms, select, angular-material

I would like to have default/initial value in material select. I tried to add [(value)]=initialValaue ,[value]=initialValue. But they don't work.
I have buildings which i list in table. And each building has few wings( i divided building in few part like in hospital you have different parts of building). And i use select do show all wings of building so user can select which one he wants. But i would like that i have default value chosen before user chooses.

```
<mat-form-field  *ngIf="getSpecificPodZg(element.key).length" >
                <mat-label>Podzgrada</mat-label>
                <mat-select [(value)]="selectedPod"  [(ngModel)]="is_selected[i]" disableOptionCentering class="mySelectClass">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let zgrada of getSpecificPodZg(element.key)" [value]="zgrada.key" required >
                    {{zgrada.ime}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field>
```

and my ts file with function

```
  getSpecificPodZg(zg_idd:String){
  

    this.SpecificPodZg=[];
    this.PodZgrada.forEach((element: any) => {
      if(element.zg_id==zg_idd){
      this.SpecificPodZg.push(element);
      }

    });
    return this.SpecificPodZg;
```

tried also this: with [selected]

```
<mat-form-field  *ngIf="getSpecificPodZg(element.key).length" >
                <mat-label>Podzgrada</mat-label>
                <mat-select   [(ngModel)]="is_selected[i]" disableOptionCentering class="mySelectClass">
                  <mat-option *ngFor="let zgrada of getSpecificPodZg(element.key); let i = index" [value]="zgrada.key" [selected]="i===0"  >
                    {{zgrada.ime}}
                  </mat-option>
                </mat-select>
              </mat-form-field
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to assign a default value to a  field, you must first bind it to a variable using ngModel:

```
  <mat-form-field  *ngIf="getSpecificPodZg(element.key).length" >
    <mat-label>Podzgrada</mat-label>
    <mat-select [(ngModel)]="initialValue">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let zgrada of table" [value]="zgrada.key" required >
        {{zgrada.ime}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

And then assign an initial value in your .ts file (the default value must be assigned from the same array, that is being used to create your mat-option elements):

```
table = [{ime: "...", "key": "..."}, {ime: "...", "key": "..."}, {ime: "...", "key": "..."}]
initialValue = table[0].key
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot about this part [(ngModel)]="initialValue" and when i saw your answer I saw mine [(ngModel)]="is_selected[i]"  was empty until i select option. So when i load data I add to is_selected[i] first value in array. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

First of all:

```
[(value)]="selectedPod" 
[(ngModel)]="is_selected[i]"
```

What's sitting under these? You try to bind two different variables here if I understand correctly. On top of that mat-option value points into a specific property `[value]="zgrada.key"` and the select value/ngModel binding should also point to the same property otherwise blank space might be displayed after initial select.

I'd recommend using reactive forms for handling the data in mat-form-fields. You can then easily subscribe to form changes in ngOnInit and output the data so you can follow the changes. Rough example (you need to include ReactiveFormsModule into your module and form related imports into actual component):

foo.component.html:

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  ...
  <mat-form-field  *ngIf="getSpecificPodZg(element.key).length" >
    <mat-label>Podzgrada</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="myListField" disableOptionCentering class="mySelectClass">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let zgrada of getSpecificPodZg(element.key)" [value]="zgrada.key" required >
        {{zgrada.ime}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
  ...
</form>
```

foo.component.ts:

```
myForm: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { }

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
    myListField: initial_value_here // here you put initial value to a select field, needs to be the same as value of option you want to pick; myListField is a formControlName used with mat-select
  });

  // listening to form changes
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe(c => {
    console.log('form changes', c);
  });
}
```